# When implement Serilog debug mode does not work [.NET Core 3.1]

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, serilog

when first implement of Serilog, dotnet core version was 2.2. Then we updated the app version to 3.1. I later saw that when I started the debug mode, the chrome page does not start.

My firs implementation is:

Program.cs:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{       

    var sinkOpts = new SinkOptions { TableName = "_Log", AutoCreateSqlTable = true, BatchPostingLimit = 10 };    

    var columnOptions = new ColumnOptions
    {
        AdditionalColumns = new Collection<SqlColumn>
        {
            new SqlColumn
                {ColumnName = "UserName", PropertyName = "UserName", DataType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, DataLength = 64},
        }
    };

    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()            
            .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                connectionString: appSettings.GetConnectionString("DB"),
                sinkOptions: sinkOpts,
                columnOptions: columnOptions,
                restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error
            ).CreateLogger();           
}
```

Then I created a middleware for catch some information from HttpContext:

```
public class LogContextMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public LogContextMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        LogContext.PushProperty("UserName", context.User.Identity.Name);

        return next(context);
    }
}
```

Finally use this middleware at Startup.cs

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseMiddleware<LogContextMiddleware>(); <--
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

That's it... This job is completely working at 2.2. Official documentation says add the "UseSerilogRequestLogging()" at Startup.cs but dont working... Where I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error message when starting the App?
The connection string is ok?

Consider that the app.UseSerilogRequestLogging or the app.UseMiddleware(); is inside the Configure(..) method and the ***order does matter***.

Finally, on the Program.cs when configuring the web host, are you calling the ".UseSerilog()" method? Otherwise, it won't work.

I hope it helps!